# Problem with AddOn-Package Theorema

Tags: packages

First of all, I'm fairly new to Mathematica and the Wolfram Environment in general. If this question has already been asked I'm sorry for the duplicate, but I haven't been able to track down the issue with searches on this site and the web.

I downloaded the AddOn-Package 'Theorema' and in the installation instructions it says that the package can be moved "into one of the locations for standard add-on packages'. In the AddOn folder that comes with the Mathematica installation there are three subdirectories: Applications, ExtraPackages and Packages. Not knowing where to put the Theorema package, I just pasted it into the Packages folder as stated in the installation instruction.

The problem now is, when I open a given .nb notebook file it immediately gives me an error that

> the stylesheet TheoremaCore cannot be found by the Wolfram System

even though I have checked and it exists within the Theorema folder.

The second problem is the 'execution' of the Theorema package. The installation instructions say:

> ...execute the first command in the notebook `Needs["Theorema"]` by placing the cursor into that cell and hitting <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

However nothing happens when I do that. I also don't know exactly what is meant by "cell".

I hope someone has some kind of advice, thank you in advance.

Comment: Put it in `FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "Applications"}]` and run ``Needs["Theorema`"]``, notice the backtick after `a`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not modify the `$InstallationDirectory` of Mathematica. Put it in `$UserBaseDirectory` instead.

Evaluate

```
SystemOpen@FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "Applications"}]
```

to get to the correct location.

The directory structure must look like this:

[image]